# How to get generated keys by executeBatch without ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, primary-key

The following method I want to INSERT several records simultaneously.

```
public void insert() {
    try {
        this.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO  COMPANY (NAME,Address) Values (?,?)", new String[]{"ID"});
        ps.setString(1, "X01");
        ps.setString(2, "Address1");
        ps.addBatch();

        ps.setString(1, "Y01");
        ps.setString(2, "Address2");
        ps.addBatch();

       //EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
        int[] numUpdates = ps.executeBatch();

        for (int i = 0; i < numUpdates.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Execution " + i +
                        "successful: " + numUpdates[i] + " rows inserted");
        }

        ResultSet resultSet =
                (ps).getGeneratedKeys();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String deptNoKey = resultSet.getString(1);
            System.out.println("Automatically generated key value = "
                    + deptNoKey);
        }
    } catch (BatchUpdateException b) {
        // process BatchUpdateException
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

At this point, when I expect to get the PK's generated for each INSERT, I get this Exception

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 22
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CNumberAccessor.unmarshalOneRow(T4CNumberAccessor.java:250)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:754)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1250)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeForRowsWithTimeout(OraclePreparedStatement.java:14264)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:14379)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:589)
>   at dbpro.SqlHelper.insert2(SqlHelper.java:988)
>   at dbpro.SqlHelper.main(SqlHelper.java:1023)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
> ```

After Exception:
     In The table COMPANY , two records are added correctly but I expected to get a ResultSet with one row for each insert performed, so I could get each PK generated.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this.  Which Oracle version are you using?  Which JDBC driver JAR?  How are the IDs generated (e.g. using a trigger, identity coiumns in 12c)?  I'm using Oracle 11g XE 11.2.0.2.0 on Linux x64, I used a trigger to set the ID values and I tried with each of ojdbc14.jar, ojdbc5.jar, ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc7.jar.  All four JARs worked as expected, apart from not getting the numbers of rows inserted.

Comment: I want to INSERT several records and get keys . So what's the solution? please send sample code . I can generate IDs by trigger , but I want get them by executeBatch in java code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'please send sample code'.  I just used your code and it worked for me.  Also, please answer the questions I asked in my first comment.

Comment: I used :  Oracle 11g XE 11.2.0.2.0 -  ojdbc6  - jdk1.8 and ids generate by triger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Oracle on Windows, the driver JAR ojdbc6.jar, or (knowing Oracle) both.

There's no significant problem with the code you have presented.  It should work, although when I ran it the numbers of rows inserted each time was returned as -2 (= [`Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#SUCCESS_NO_INFO)), so you may be better off ignoring these numbers.

Your code runs fine for me with Oracle 11g XE 11.2.0.2.0 on Linux with four versions of the Oracle JDBC driver JAR.  However, if I run it on Windows 10 with the same version of Oracle XE and with ojdbc6.jar, it fails with the same ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException you are getting.  The problem goes away if I use ojdbc7.jar instead of ojdbc6.jar.

Therefore, I would recommend replacing ojdbc6.jar with ojdbc7.jar, which you can download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and tips.