# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CNumberAccessor.unmarshalOneRow(T4CNumberAccessor.java:201)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have no clue what is the cause of this issue.
The table fundFactor has 30,000 rows ,and I set prepareStatement fetchSize is 30,000
Then I got this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2100000
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CNumberAccessor.unmarshalOneRow(T4CNumberAccessor.java:201)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:945)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:865)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readRXD(T4C8Oall.java:790)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:403)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
```

Here is My code:

```
                Connection oracleConn = DriverManager.getConnection(oracleUrl, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
                PreparedStatement ps = oracleConn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setFetchSize(oracleFetch);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()){
                    System.out.println("next over!");
                    rs.getString(2);
                }
```

The error happens when execute : `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();`

version : ojdbc6, 11.2.0.4 ,oracle11g . Running on linux X64

When i set fetchsize 600000,then it shows:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4200000
```

Thats interesting, it seems ojdbc fetchs 7 times defaultly.
Does anyone knows how can i avoid this ?

This is my sql :
`select * from fundFactor`
Thats all

Comment: 70 times, maybe because of joining tables, 70 = 7 x 5 x 2. (Could be a forgotten `ON x.pk = y.fk`) Apart from the apparent limitation, it also might be counter-productive to use a large fetch size; measure times of 100, 200, and so on.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? [This sounds similar if so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33596338/266304), though with a different method call and smaller numbers... Are you able to test with a later version of ojdbc? And why do you want to get all the data in a single huge fetch - you're trading what may be a small reduction in network time with a much larger memory requirement.

Comment: What SQL query are you using?

Comment: Thank for your comments. My SQL query is simple : select * from fundFactor; That's all.

Comment: @AlexPoole Not on Windows , Linux . I know it's huge,but i need this , don't worry about memory . I'll try ojdbc7 later.

Comment: @JoopEggen 7 time , i am sure. I set fetchSize : 599999 , then shows error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4199993 . That's Interesting, lol

Comment: @f.g Can you check if this is the behavior with the latest version of the driver? 19c or 21c. Or Is this happening only with 11.2.0.4?

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried ojdbc8 , version : 12.2.0.1 . Problems resolved , thanks .